# How to show date as day of week?

Tags: list, formatting, default-value

It seems like an obvious request, but I could not find an answer.

Within a list, how do I show the day of the week for a date?

More specifically, how to show day of week for a default value for the column?

Answer (score 4):

Using the defined system value, `[TODAY]`, we can calculate the current date for a default by simply adding:

```
[TODAY]
```

To get the *day of week*, use the `WEEKDAY()` function:

```
=WEEKDAY([TODAY])
```

Now we have the day *number* of the week. Using the `TEXT()` function we can format it as we please. To get the day of the week, use:

### TLDR;

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([TODAY]), "dddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weekday as text from a date field by this formula,

```
=TEXT([DATE_FIELD], "dddd")
```